# css transition on the Ipad with text

Tags: html, css, ipad, text, css-transitions

I am working on a project for my self. I made some img with a hover transition.

It works perfect in all browsers. But not on the ipad. Why? For some reasons i cant click on the the image because of the text. I dont know why that is. I got 2 examples:

**Example 1:**
http://jewelbeast.com/imghover/ If you test this 1 on the ipad and you click on the img. You will see that nothing happends. Because the text in Centered with **vertical align** and with **text-align:**.

**Example 2**
http://jewelbeast.com/imghover/test.html if you test this 1 on the ipad you can click on the right side of the image. Because there is no text on the right side.

**CSS**

```
div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder{
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 228px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section{
    position: relative;
    width: 217px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    outline: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;

    overflow: hidden;
    background: #dfdfdf;
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section:hover{
    height: 380px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}


div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section img{
    position: absolute;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section .text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section span{
    width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;

    opacity: 0;

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section:hover span{
    opacity: 1;
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section:hover img{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section span h1{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section span p{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section span a.button{
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;

    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;

    padding: 9px 10px 11px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #616161;
    outline: 1px solid #000000;

    background: #494949; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #494949 1%, #3a3a3a 94%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#494949), color-stop(94%,#3a3a3a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #494949 1%,#3a3a3a 94%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #494949 1%,#3a3a3a 94%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #494949 1%,#3a3a3a 94%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #494949 1%,#3a3a3a 94%); /* W3C */
}

div.hover-img-vertical-smallborder section span a.entire{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="hover-img-vertical-smallborder">
        <section class="bg-black"> <!-- bg-black is a black background on hover normal is grey -->
            <img src="img/img_5.jpg" style="left: -50%;"/>
            <div class="text">
                <span>
                    <h1>This is a title</h1>
                </span>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

I hope somebody can figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hover event fired on a touch device. You need to use either one of these events in JS:

```
touchstart
touchmove
touchend
touchcancel
```

Comment: You can use modernizer (http://modernizr.com/) to detect a touch device then change your styles according to whether it is on a touch device or not